# Publish into facebook wall from flex mobile

Tags: android, iphone, flex4.5

I'm building a mobile app using flex 4.5 that should be able to post/share a message to the facebook wall.
I've find examples for desktop app, but I am not getting any examples for mobile app. Can someone help me?

Comment: What examples have you found and how did what they described/demonstrated not work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new [FacebookMobile class](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/) for posting to the wall etc.